# ¿Como poner el cursor en la primera linea de un JTextPane?

Tags: java, html, netbeans

Agrego el contenido del **JTextPane** en el constructor del formulario que lo contiene con estas lineas :

```
jtextpane.setContentType("text/html");

jtextpane.setText("<html><body><font color=#16a085 size=6> Hola a todos! </font></body></html>");
```

*pero mi contenido es de muchas **lineas(50)**, entonces el contructor al momento de escribir todo el contenido **html** en el **JTextPane** el **ScrollBar** vertical  se va hasta abajo , mostrando asi el contenido final de **JTextPane** , lo que deseo es que el se visualiza las primeras lineas del **JTextPane** no las ultimas.

Answer (score 1):

La manera más sencilla es utilizando el método [setCaretPosition(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition(int)), el cual coloca el cursor en cualquier punto del texto contenido dentro del text pane. Para colocarlo al inicio, la llamada sería pasándole *cero* como parámetro

```
jtextpane.setCaretPosition(0);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias mi hermano, me resolviste el problema, que Dios te bendiga.